# convert pixel-coordinates to data-coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a plot with `matplotlib.pyplot`. For this image I need a function that maps pixel-coordinates to the coordinates of the data  (for interaction with the user in another GUI-system outside of python). I have tried the function `ax.transData.inverted().transform(x)`, since it maps display-coordinates to data-coordinates. But the numbers that I get have an offset of roughly 23 pixels in x-direction. I went through [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html), but I could not find anything on this problem.

I have also tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13662938/3182044) from stackoverflow, where the printed x-coordinates have an offset of 25 pixels. I could see that  Maybe the area left to the y-axis is not included there? I definitely need it to be included.
In the attached picture I am comparing what the code from stackoverflow yields vs what MS paint tells me about the x-coordinate of the red dot. They are not the same.

[image: Datapoints from the code example]

Comment: `ax.transData.inverted().transform(x)` would indeed give you the data coordinates of `x` defined in pixels. I could of course provide an answer proving that to be the case, but I suppose that's not what you're looking for. Instead you may want to make your case reproducible, such that one can help you find out where you took the wrong turn.

Comment: In the post I have provided a link to the code, that I am talking about. You can run it immediately and should see similar results. ps: someone edited my text for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, `ax.transData.inverted().transform(x)` does indeed give you the data coordinates of `x` defined in pixels.

So we run

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
points, = ax.plot(range(10), 'ro')
ax.axis([-1, 10, -1, 10])
fig.savefig("test.png")
```

open the saved picture in Irfanview and mark the dot at (0,0).

[image]

As seen in the image, it's at `(126, 86)` pixels. So plugging in this tuple

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
points, = ax.plot(range(10), 'ro')
ax.axis([-1, 10, -1, 10])

x = 126, 86
point = ax.transData.inverted().transform(x)
print(point)
```

We get

```
[ 0.02016129 -0.01190476]
```

which is as close to `(0,0)` as you can get, given that the pixel resolution is

```
x2 = 125, 85
point2 = ax.transData.inverted().transform(x2)
print(point - point2)

[0.02217742 0.0297619 ]
```

and hence larger than those obtained numbers.

This might arguably not answer the question, but it is all one *can possibly* say here, with the information from the question at hand.