# Pixel coordinates of matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am referencing this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662525/how-to-get-pixel-coordinates-for-matplotlib-generated-scatterplot) and implementing the solution, however I am getting very large values.  Thanks for any help, attached it the code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_labels = ['x1','x2','x3']
y_values = [30,40,50]

coordList = []
x_vals = []
i = 0
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for item in x_labels:
    x_vals.append(i)
    i+=1
points, = ax.plot(x_vals, y_values)
x, y = points.get_data()
print(x, y)
xy_pixels = ax.transData.transform(np.vstack([x,y]).T)
xpix, ypix = xy_pixels.T
for xp, yp in zip(xpix, ypix):
    coordList.append(f'{xp}, {yp}')
print(coordList)
```

Here is a resulting coordList:

['80.0, 39969.6', '576.0, 37382.4', '1072.0, 34425.6', '1568.0, 31838.399999999998', '2064.0, 29620.799999999996', '2560.0, 26663.999999999996', '3056.0, 24815.999999999996', '3552.0, 21859.199999999997', '4048.0, 19271.999999999996']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is the original transformation **prior to the internal automatic setting of the axes bounds**. In order to force an update of the transformation, you need to either get the bounds by e.g `get_xbounds()` or completely update the figure first by calling `fig.canvas.draw()` (in the linked example the update was ensured by `ax.axis([-1, 10, -1, 10])`).

```
ax.get_xbound()
xy_pixels = ax.transData.transform(np.vstack([x,y]).T)
```

Result (for my display):

```
[0 1 2] [30 40 50]
['102.54545454545455, 69.59999999999997', '328.0, 237.59999999999997', '553.4545454545454, 405.59999999999997']
```

[source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18220#issuecomment-672293833)